# How to add not too and bottom app bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having a problem putting both an app bar and bottom app bar in flutter.
I create a Scaffold and use the app bar and bottomNavigationBar properties. I use AppBar and BottomAppBar respectively. But when I run it only the bottom app bar will show and not the top app bar. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to have both a bottom app bar and top app bar?

Comment: add your codes, buddy.

Comment: add some code what you have tried.

Comment: I apologize, new here. Next time I have an issue I will submit code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, maybe the child of the BottomAppBar has no height, here a working example:

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Title'),
  ),
  body: Center(child: Text('Center')),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.home),
          Icon(Icons.pause_circle_filled),
          Icon(Icons.settings)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```